# stri_trans_general fails at certain cyrlic letters

Tags: r, stringi

I'm using stri_trans_general to convert Macedonian cyrlic alphabet to Latin letters.

However, I've noticed that certain letters, specific to Macedonian, and which differ from other cyrlic alphabets... such as: Ј, Њ, Ѕ, Ж, and so on.. do not get translated.

For example:

```
stri_trans_general('ДРАГИ', 'latin')
[1] "DRAGI"
> 
> stri_trans_general('Чуден', 'latin')
[1] "**Č**uden"
```

For the second example, I will get a wierd html code for the first letter.

Edit:

[image]

The picture shows how this looks in particular.

The problem I have is that if I try to geocode an address, which contains these encoding issues, I won't get the correct coordinates.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Well, what "fix" do you want exactly? What is the translation you expect in this case? What is the desired output?

Comment: @MrFlick I have updated the question. Hope its a bit clearer.

Comment: Still not clear. You show what you are getting - you have not shown what you want instead. *What is the desired output?*

Comment: cannot reproduce on R 3.3.2, platform x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit).  For the problematic example I get `"Čuden"`

Comment: @Gregor I want to store the result in a dataframe, without the encoding issue. If you see the third row. the original Address does not get translated for the second word and instead gets <U+1FA>.

Comment: @drammock I'm using R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit). The problem occurs when you store the result in a dataframe though.

Comment: Still cannot reproduce even if I put the result in a `data.frame`.  I also tried on Windows, R 3.1.2, platform x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit).  On windows, `stri_trans_general('Чуден', 'latin')` works fine (yields `"Čuden"`); when I put the result in a dataframe it displays as `"Cuden"` (without the hacek) but doesn't have asterisks like your example.